# Ruby palindrome words in a text file

Tags: ruby, palindrome

I am trying to write a ruby program that is going to find and display the palindrome words saved in a file example: (c:/palindrome.txt). The idea is to read the content of the file (a couple of words) and print palindrome words only.

```
@string=""
File.new("C:\\palindrome.txt", "r").each do |line|
@string += line
end
```

Comment: You need to give much more information. What have you tried so far? Paste some code. If it's a specific error you're running into, let us know what that error is.

Comment: Please be more specific about the contents of the file. Does it contain punctuation? Is there one word per line? Are some words capitalized and others not? Please edit your question rather than explain in a comment.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Have you considered that others may be preparing answers? Also, quick selections may discourage other, possibly better, answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours. The point is, there's no rush.

Comment: The answer simply suits my needs and it solves my question. On the other hand others may still try to help me even though I get the proper answer already. That is how I can save other people time thought.

Comment: Please respond to the request in my first comment. You owe it to those who will read this question in future.

Comment: Sorry Cary Swoveland, to be honest the content of the file was not specified, because I was open for any suggestions.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered unless one assumes the file has a particular structure. The question now reads that the file structure is fixed but unspecified. If you want those giving answers to also propose the file structure, you need to say so, but I think it would be better to just specify a structure, such as a string containing words (some possibly capitalized) separated by spaces or one word per line, all lower case. The former is consistent with the selected answer, so I would go with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work

```
words = File.read("c:/palindrome.txt")
words_array = words.downcase.split(" ")

palindromes = []

words_array.each do |word|
    if word.length>1
        palindromes << word if word == word.reverse
    end
end

puts palindromes
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Maybe use: words_array.select{|w| w.length > 1 && w == w.reverse}

Comment: You may want to use `split` without an argument, which is the same as `split(/\s+/)`. @David, why?

Comment: It seems to me to be more idiomatic to chain the methods in that fashion. Semantically speaking, the task is to select from the array those elements which match a condition, and my suggested method is more closely aligned with that, I think -- you'd look at it and say "Ah yes, this is selecting from an array those elements which match a condition".

Comment: Taking it a bit further, you might decide that you could create a new class Word that inherits from String, and put a method on that to define whether the Word instance is a palindrome or not as well as all your other word-related behaviours. Then you could: string_array.map{|s| Word.new(s)}.select(&:palindrome?)  That would be quite good fun.

Comment: @tadman The whole file gets downcased on line 2.

Comment: Ah, I see that now.